# objective c: unable to read the name of mutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Hi I can't get the name of the mutable array inside another mutable array

```
NSMutableArray *array1;
NSMutableArray *array2;
NSMutableArray *Section;

array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"row 1", @"row 2",nil];
array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"row one", @"row two", @"row three", @"row four",nil];

Section = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[Section addObject: array1];
[Section addObject: array2];
```

when I try to get the name but I get this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[Section objectAtIndex:0]);
```

and this is the output:

```
"row 1",
"row 2"
```

How can I be able to get the name array1 and array2?

expected output is:

array1

Comment: The "name"? What do you mean exactly ? The name of the var? Could you show the expected output?

Comment: aren't you looking to use a NSMutableDictionary instead of a NSMutableArray? (to have a key => array association)

Comment: I want to get the array name instead of the array content

Comment: **Why** do you expect that output?  "array1" is just a placeholder in a source file.  When it has been compiled, it's nothing but an address that holds another address.  To do what your asking, you'll need to store @"array1" somewhere and use that.  (Perhaps make `Section` a dictionary.)

Comment: I want to get the string, bro is there a way to get it? I cast the object to string but can't

Comment: I just show the expected output i want to @Larme

Comment: If you want to show a string, you need to save a string.  The name of a variable isn't a string when the program runs (with some fairly advanced exceptions).

Comment: That's mean there is no way to do this?

Comment: I repeat, 'you'll need to store @"array1" somewhere and use that'.

Comment: You need to learn a lot about programming if you even expect that there might be some possibility that this would be doable.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot guy I learnt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What follows is of course illustrative, but this is in essence what is going on.*

You appear to have misunderstood what a *variable* is, it is just a box. When you write:

```
NSInteger rowCount;
```

you are requesting that the system find a box, from its pile of unused boxes, which is just the right size to store a *value* of type `NSInteger`. The are a lot of boxes in a computer and it needs a away to distinguish one from another, so each has a *name*. That name is pretty incomprehensible, something like:

```
0000000000001101000111001110110110111110111011111100101011111110
```

as computers usually only use 0's and 1's. You can't use that in a computer program you'd keep typing it wrong, and it is pretty meaningless even if you code it up into something more reasonable to a human:

```
D1CEDBEEFCAFE
```

it remains rather meaningless.

*(They really are the same! But of course I picked those 0'1 and 1's carefully, most names are not so memorable.)*

Given this computer languages allow you to use a more readable and meaningful name, `rowCount` above, to refer to the box you requested - the compiler keeps a mapping from your name to the real one.

**Important:** All the above is about how the *variable* (aka box) is named, it has *nothing* to do with the *value* that you might put in the box. So when you write:

```
rowCount = 42;
```

The value `42` hasn't gained an alternative name of `rowCount`, all that has happened is the value `42` has been placed in the box named `rowCount` (in our example a convenient name for the computers box `D1CEDBEEFCAFE`). If you later write:

NSInteger anotherRowCount = rowCount;

then the *value* in `rowCount`, currently `42`, is copied into the box named `anotherRowCount`. If you look into the `anotherRowCount` box all you see is `42`, there is no mention that value came from `rowCount`.

**Variable names and the values those variables contain are distinct, and there is no connection between the name and the value.**

Now if you look back at your code it is a bit more involved, rather than boxes holding `NSInteger` values you have ones holding `NSMutableArray *` values - but that doesn't change the essence of what is going on, a box is a box.

You start by asking for three boxes, and then you put values in the ones you've named `array1` and `array2`.

Next you put a value in the box you've named `section` (*always start variable names with a lowercase letter*). The *value* you placed in `section` is not simple, like `42`, but one which can hold other values.

You then *copy* the *values* in your two boxes `array1` and `array2` and add them to the `value` you've stored in box `section`. Those copied values have nothing to do with the box names they come from, the box names `array1` and `array2` are not copied into the *value* stored in box `section`.

**So what is the *value* stored in boxes `array1`, `array2` and `section`?**

Try not to go cross-eyed at this point...

Above I said that the value stored in `section` is not simple, like `42`, but one which can hold other values. The same is true for `array1` and `array2`. But what is that value? Well it is something of type `NSMutableArray *`, we know that as that is what we asked for - three boxes which can hold `NSMutableArray *` values.

The `*` in `NSMutableArray *` means "box name"! So the type `NSMutableArray *` is "box name of a box holding an `NSMutableArray` value". When you write:

```
section = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

the right hand side is an instruction to find a box capable of holding an `NSMutableArray` *value* (Note: no `*`), and this instruction returns the *name* of that box as its value. That value is stored in `section`. And that value is not something like `aBigBoxWhichCanHoldAnNSMutableArray`, or even `fred`, the instruction above doesn't give it a nice friendly name - it is just the computers name for the box, something like:

```
1101111010101101111110101100111011011110101011011111101011001110
```

What all this means is that when you write:

```
[section addObject: array1];
```

the *value* in `array1` is copied into the *value* stored in `section`. That *value* is a *box name*, but it is certainly not `"array1"` or even the computers real name for the box you've called `array1`. It is the name stored inside that box, and that name is essentially meaningless to you - a long string of 0's and 1's.

Hope that helps more than it confuses!

Comment: Finally I was using NSDictionary to solve the storing structure of my data =)